# Use elastic search in side all data from big database

Tags: database, elasticsearch

Following this link, I have decided to index all the information in elasticsearch in addition to the main database of the site, and then the information displayed to the users of the site will be taken from elastic search, such as displaying the latest news and searching among hundreds of thousands of news... Is this  The method is correct and can I show thousands of pages following a search like Earth, I know it is possible but why is it not good in this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/general-recommendations.html#large-size

Comment: How large is your news by average ? Generally, a news can be 10k  at most which is OK to ES.

Comment: Considering that 10k is suitable, is it suitable for 100k?